# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} = \frac{1}{2}$ by closing the sum in with two integral estimates

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

Show that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Attempted answer:**

My thinking is that we should close in the sum with the help of two integrals. Hopefully this will resolve the entire expression as the left part goes towards zero as n goes to infinity and both come out as $1/2$

What integrals should we use? I am thinking:

$$ \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{2x} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} \leq \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}$$

Let us evaluate the two integrals:

$$ \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{2x} = \frac{\ln{x}}{2} + C_{1}$$

$$ \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} = \ln{x} + C_{2}$$

So regardless of the situation, we can get rid of the $\ln{n}$ in the denominator from the original expression.

Using the first integral, the expression evaluates to $1/2$, and the second to $1$.

However, this does not persuade me that the answer is really $1/2$. After all, it could be anywhere between the two (inclusive).

**How to complete the solution to this question? Is it better to choose integral estimates of the sum instead? If so, which should be used?**

Comment: Your upper bound is overly generous. Can you make it more restrictive, and ideally closer to  $(\ln x ) / 2$?  EG Clearly we can bound it by $ \frac{ 2}{3x}$ which gives us a bound of $ (2 \ln x ) / 3 $. How can we do better?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}=H_{2n}-\frac12H_n$$ where $H_m$ in the $m$th harmonic number. Then use $H_m=\log m+O(1).$

Comment: Use your method to prove that : $$\lim \dfrac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k = 1}^{2 n} \dfrac{1}{k} = 1$$ and notice that : $$\dfrac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k = 1}^{2 n} \dfrac{1}{k} = \dfrac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{2 k} + \dfrac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{2k - 1} $$

Comment: [Stolz–Cesàro theorem 1](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stolzcesaro-theorem/)

Comment: @CalvinLin How about 1/(2k-2)?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Another beautiful approach, but too advanced for the problem I am working on. I think I am stuck with the integral estimates approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your integral bounds so that the sum you gave will be an upper Riemann sum for the lower bound and a lower Riemann sum for the upper bound. You did that for the lower bound case, for the upper bound case:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1}= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k+1}$$
Now you can think of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}$ as the lower Riemann sum of $\frac{1}{2x+1}$ from $x=0$ to $n$. So $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} \leq \int_0^n \frac{1}{2x+1}$. Thus:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} \leq 1 + \frac{\ln(2n+1)}{2}$$
So showing that $\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln(n)}$ approaches $1$ will suffice. And for that, notice $\frac{\ln(2n+1) - \ln(2n)}{\ln(n)}$ approaches $0$ and $\frac{\ln(2n)}{ln(n)} = \frac{\ln(2) + \ln(n)}{\ln(n)}$ approaches $1$. Thus $\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln(n)} = \frac{\ln(2n+1) - \ln(2n)}{\ln(n)} + \frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln(n)}$ approaches $1$.

Comment: So the upper bound that I am looking for is this?

$$\int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{2x} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} \leq 1+ \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{2x+1}$$

Comment: @MathInferno Yes.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to show that $\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln{n}}$ approaches 1?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} \leq 1 + \frac{\ln(2n+1)}{2}$, so $\frac{1}{\ln n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} \leq \frac{1}{\ln n} +  \frac{\ln(2n+1)}{2\ln n}$, if we show that fact we see that the right hand side approaches $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I also noticed that in the comment you have putted $1$ as the lower bound of the integral at the right, It should be $0$ as stated in the answer.

Comment: so it should be:

$$\int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{2x} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} \leq 1+ \int_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{2x+1}$$

Comment: Yes, this is the correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use the fact that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{2k-2} = \dfrac{x^{n}-1}{x-1}$$
And integrating both sides, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1} =  \int \dfrac{x^{n}-1}{x-1}dx$$

After integrating the right side and putting the value $x=1$, we get the desired expression.

Comment: Wow, that was a very creative solution that I did not even consider. However, the hint for the question suggests that I should use a method whereby I close in the sum with two integral estimates. Although I have no doubts that your solution is neater and frankly more beautiful, I would like to attempt the enclosure approach.

Comment: After applying some corrections, your method gives $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1} = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1}\,dx$$ (note that while the $x^n$ v. $x^{2n}$ won't matter in the eventual limit, the additional factor of $x+1$ in the denominator is necessary for the $1/2$ to appear).

Comment: @BrianMoehring So the upper bound that I am looking for is this?

$$\int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{2x} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} \leq  \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^2-1}$$

Comment: No.  This method has nothing to do with the integral bounds.  It allows you to write the series as an integral exactly, the evaluation of which, in theory, should give you the answer directly.  In practice, I don't see how it's helpful without some additional estimations.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in[k,k+1]$, we have $k\in[x-1,x]$. So
$$ 2x-3\le 2k-1\le 2x-1 $$
or
$$ \frac1{2x-1}\le\frac1{2k-1}\le\frac1{2k-3}.$$
Thus
$$ \frac12\ln(2n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_k^{k+1}\frac1{2x-1}dx\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}\le1+ \sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac1{2x-3}dx=1+\frac12\ln(2n-1).$$
From this, it is easy to get the result by the Squeeze Theorem.